# Django best way to get latest values after update?

Tags: django

My django project has 2 models, User and Profile

I have the code to update the profile using a dictionary `**profile`

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

Profile.objects.filter(id=request.user.profile.id).update(**profile)
print(model_to_dict(request.user.profile))
```

The print statement prints the old value I guess it's because the lazy query in the first statement `id=request.user.profile.id`

So for me to refresh profile, the only way right now I can think of is:

```
request.user.profile = Profile.objects.get(id=request.user.profile.id)
```

But to me this is not elegant, just wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

no. massive updates don't refresh the instantiated (inflated, let's say) model objects. django is just an orm but not an entity manager in the same way, e.g., Hibernate is (and i don't think that's neither supported in hibernate). no track of instances and ids are done, and that line is translated only into sql.

Answer (score 0):

Found this

https://gist.github.com/kipanshi/3859962

Might worth creating a mixin:

```
class UpdateMixin(object):

    def refresh(self):
        return self.__class__.objects.get(pk=self.pk)


    def update(self, **data):
        self.__class__.objects.filter(pk=self.pk).update(**data)
        return self.refresh()


class Profile(UpdateMixin, models.Model):
    ....
```